# Jupyter Lab Desktop App cannot instal FbProphet

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, jupyter-notebook, facebook-prophet

I am currently using a x64 AMD processor on windows 10 and I am trying to install JupyterLab on my Desktop application (Jupyter released one not so long ago).

Whenever I Try to install fbprophet, I get the following error:

```
    pip install fbprophet
Collecting fbprophet
  Using cached fbprophet-0.7.1.tar.gz (64 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: Cython>=0.22 in c:\jupyterlab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (0.29.28)
Collecting cmdstanpy==0.9.5
  Using cached cmdstanpy-0.9.5-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pystan>=2.14 in c:\jupyterlab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (2.19.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in c:\jupyterlab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (1.21.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=1.0.4 in c:\jupyterlab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (1.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=2.0.0 in c:\jupyterlab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (3.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: LunarCalendar>=0.0.9 in c:\jupyterlab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (0.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: convertdate>=2.1.2 in c:\jupyterlab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (2.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: holidays>=0.10.2 in c:\jupyterlab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (0.13)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools-git>=1.2 in c:\jupyterlab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.0 in c:\jupyterlab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.36.1 in c:\jupyterlab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (4.62.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pymeeus<=1,>=0.3.13 in c:\jupyterlab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages (from convertdate>=2.1.2->fbprophet) (0.5.11)
Requirement already satisfied: korean-lunar-calendar in c:\jupyterlab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages (from holidays>=0.10.2->fbprophet) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: hijri-converter in c:\jupyterlab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages (from holidays>=0.10.2->fbprophet) (2.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: ephem>=3.7.5.3 in c:\jupyterlab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages (from LunarCalendar>=0.0.9->fbprophet) (4.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\jupyterlab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages (from LunarCalendar>=0.0.9->fbprophet) (2021.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\jupyterlab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->fbprophet) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in c:\jupyterlab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->fbprophet) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in c:\jupyterlab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->fbprophet) (8.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\jupyterlab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->fbprophet) (1.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\jupyterlab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib>=2.0.0->fbprophet) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\jupyterlab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages (from tqdm>=4.36.1->fbprophet) (0.4.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: fbprophet
  Building wheel for fbprophet (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for fbprophet (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for fbprophet
Failed to build fbprophet
Installing collected packages: cmdstanpy, fbprophet
  Attempting uninstall: cmdstanpy
    Found existing installation: cmdstanpy 0.9.68
    Uninstalling cmdstanpy-0.9.68:
      Successfully uninstalled cmdstanpy-0.9.68
    Running setup.py install for fbprophet: started
    Running setup.py install for fbprophet: finished with status 'error'
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Boggart\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h1jzab0z\\fbprophet_90b4b294e2d845389ddc39740ff76cc9\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Boggart\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h1jzab0z\\fbprophet_90b4b294e2d845389ddc39740ff76cc9\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Boggart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-a1267jzm'
       cwd: C:\Users\Boggart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h1jzab0z\fbprophet_90b4b294e2d845389ddc39740ff76cc9\
  Complete output (56 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib
  creating build\lib\fbprophet
  creating build\lib\fbprophet\stan_model
  --- Logging error ---
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1088, in emit
      stream.write(msg + self.terminator)
  ValueError: underlying buffer has been detached
  Call stack:
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Boggart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h1jzab0z\fbprophet_90b4b294e2d845389ddc39740ff76cc9\setup.py", line 122, in <module>
      setup(
    File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 87, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      return run_commands(dist)
    File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 163, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 136, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Boggart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h1jzab0z\fbprophet_90b4b294e2d845389ddc39740ff76cc9\setup.py", line 48, in run
      build_models(target_dir)
    File "C:\Users\Boggart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h1jzab0z\fbprophet_90b4b294e2d845389ddc39740ff76cc9\setup.py", line 38, in build_models
      StanBackendEnum.get_backend_class(backend).build_model(target_dir, MODEL_DIR)
    File "C:\Users\Boggart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h1jzab0z\fbprophet_90b4b294e2d845389ddc39740ff76cc9\fbprophet\models.py", line 214, in build_model
      sm = pystan.StanModel(model_code=model_code)
    File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\pystan\model.py", line 259, in __init__
      logger.info(msg.format(self.model_name))
  Message: 'COMPILING THE C++ CODE FOR MODEL anon_model_f5236004a3fd5b8429270d00efcc0cf9 NOW.'
  Arguments: ()
  MSVC compiler is not supported
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fbprophet
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Boggart\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h1jzab0z\\fbprophet_90b4b294e2d845389ddc39740ff76cc9\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Boggart\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h1jzab0z\\fbprophet_90b4b294e2d845389ddc39740ff76cc9\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Boggart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-yjmhztpp\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\Include\fbprophet'
         cwd: C:\Users\Boggart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h1jzab0z\fbprophet_90b4b294e2d845389ddc39740ff76cc9\
    Complete output (60 lines):
    running install
    C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib
    creating build\lib\fbprophet
    creating build\lib\fbprophet\stan_model
    --- Logging error ---
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1088, in emit
        stream.write(msg + self.terminator)
    ValueError: underlying buffer has been detached
    Call stack:
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Boggart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h1jzab0z\fbprophet_90b4b294e2d845389ddc39740ff76cc9\setup.py", line 122, in <module>
        setup(
      File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 87, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        return run_commands(dist)
      File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 163, in run_commands
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
        super().run_command(command)
      File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 68, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\install.py", line 670, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
        super().run_command(command)
      File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 136, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
        super().run_command(command)
      File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Boggart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h1jzab0z\fbprophet_90b4b294e2d845389ddc39740ff76cc9\setup.py", line 48, in run
        build_models(target_dir)
      File "C:\Users\Boggart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h1jzab0z\fbprophet_90b4b294e2d845389ddc39740ff76cc9\setup.py", line 38, in build_models
        StanBackendEnum.get_backend_class(backend).build_model(target_dir, MODEL_DIR)
      File "C:\Users\Boggart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h1jzab0z\fbprophet_90b4b294e2d845389ddc39740ff76cc9\fbprophet\models.py", line 214, in build_model
        sm = pystan.StanModel(model_code=model_code)
      File "C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\lib\site-packages\pystan\model.py", line 259, in __init__
        logger.info(msg.format(self.model_name))
    Message: 'COMPILING THE C++ CODE FOR MODEL anon_model_f5236004a3fd5b8429270d00efcc0cf9 NOW.'
    Arguments: ()
    MSVC compiler is not supported
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Boggart\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h1jzab0z\\fbprophet_90b4b294e2d845389ddc39740ff76cc9\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Boggart\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h1jzab0z\\fbprophet_90b4b294e2d845389ddc39740ff76cc9\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Boggart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-yjmhztpp\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\JupyterLab\resources\jlab_server\Include\fbprophet' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have Already Tried every single possible way and configuration with C++ 14 which is currently installed, so the Classic "Install the Microsoft C++ Build Tools" suggestion won't work.
I know there are no problems with the Package itself, cause I successfully installed it on conda and on JupyterLab (browser IDE).

Does Anyone By chances have a solution? I feel like it has to be with the Editor (JupyterLab Destop Application that you can find here: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have Installed the C++ Builds Tools, and assuming YOU HAVE INSTALLED also anaconda on your pc (Jupyter web App to be clear), basically you have got to activate the environment through the conda prompt.

Some Desktop IDE mess with Dependencies, Etc, so if you're using a Desktop IDE (PyCharm, Spyder, Jupyter Desktop, Etc), to activate packages from conda to your server and python environment, you have to go to the conda prompt and do as follows:

```
conda env list
```

then locate your environment

```
conda activate name-of-your-environment
```

then install whatever package you want through the conda prompt, for example:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pystan
```

have a good one y'all